# SQLAlchemy Link tables with m:n relationship

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to create the orm classes for my database.
I have a table song, a table artist and a table song_artist to fix the m:n relationship.

```py
class Song(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'songs'

    SONG_ID: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    ALBUM_ID: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('albums.ALBUM_ID'), nullable=False)
    GENRE_ID: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('genres.GENRE_ID'), nullable=False)
    FILE_ID: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('files.FILE_ID'), nullable=False)
    DURATION: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer)
    TITLE: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    RELEASE_DATE: Mapped[Date] = mapped_column(Date)

    file: Mapped['File'] = relationship(back_populates="song")
    album: Mapped['Album'] = relationship(back_populates="song")
    genre: Mapped['Genre'] = relationship(back_populates="song")
    artist: Mapped[List['Artist']] = relationship(secondary="songs_artists", back_populates="song"

class Artist(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'artists'

    ARTIST_ID: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ARTIST_NAME: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))

    song: Mapped['Song'] = relationship(secondary="songs_artists",back_populates="artist")

songs_artists = Table(
    'songs_artists',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('SONG_ID', Integer, ForeignKey('songs.SONG_ID'), primary_key=True),
    Column('ARTIST_ID', Integer, ForeignKey('artists.ARTIST_ID'), primary_key=True)
)
```

I get following error Message:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[Artist(artists)], expression 'songs_artists' failed to locate a name ("name 'songs_artists' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'src.database.musicDB.db_model_artist.Artist'> class after both dependent classes have been defined`.

I tried to change the tables now for hours, but couldn´t solve the problem.

Would be gratefull for any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

0. Please, next time you will ask question, remove from code all unrelated information (fields like `file`, `album`, etc..) and include imports and test code. By providing working code you help people who want to help you
1. since it's many to many relations, use plural form of words "song" and "artist" and `Mapped[List[...]]` type to describe relations:

```
    artists: Mapped[List["Artist"]] = relationship(
        secondary="songs_artists", back_populates="songs"
    )
```

```
    songs: Mapped[List["Song"]] = relationship(
        secondary="songs_artists", back_populates="artists"
    )
```

Working example:

```
from typing import List

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    DeclarativeBase,
    Mapped,
    mapped_column,
    relationship,
    sessionmaker,
)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Song(Base):
    __tablename__ = "songs"

    SONG_ID: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True
    )

    # ALBUM_ID: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('albums.ALBUM_ID'), nullable=False)
    # GENRE_ID: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('genres.GENRE_ID'), nullable=False)
    # FILE_ID: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('files.FILE_ID'), nullable=False)
    # DURATION: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer)
    TITLE: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    # RELEASE_DATE: Mapped[Date] = mapped_column(Date)

    # file: Mapped['File'] = relationship(back_populates="song")
    # album: Mapped['Album'] = relationship(back_populates="song")
    # genre: Mapped['Genre'] = relationship(back_populates="song")
    artists: Mapped[List["Artist"]] = relationship(
        secondary="songs_artists", back_populates="songs"
    )

class Artist(Base):
    __tablename__ = "artists"

    ARTIST_ID: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ARTIST_NAME: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))

    songs: Mapped[List["Song"]] = relationship(
        secondary="songs_artists", back_populates="artists"
    )

songs_artists = Table(
    "songs_artists",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("SONG_ID", Integer, ForeignKey("songs.SONG_ID"), primary_key=True),
    Column("ARTIST_ID", Integer, ForeignKey("artists.ARTIST_ID"), primary_key=True),
)


engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
with session_maker() as session:
    song_1 = Song(TITLE="s 1")
    song_2 = Song(TITLE="s 2")

    artist_1 = Artist(ARTIST_NAME="a 1", songs=[song_1])
    artist_2 = Artist(ARTIST_NAME="a 2", songs=[song_1, song_2])

    session.add_all((song_1, song_2, artist_1, artist_2))
    session.commit()
```

Comment: they are most probably using the wrong `Base`(and by extension `metadata`)  leading them to this issue, I doubt the code shown here and their actual code are the same. copy pasting their code and adding imports and removing stuff you mentioned works fine

Comment: Actually, the problem is in the lines with `relationship`. I've just tried to change these lines in my example and got the same error

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. That was another error)